# Dynamic Color in Layout Editor doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, material-ui, material3

I updated Android Studio and noticed a new feature - changing dynamic colors in Layout Editor. I want to try it out but unfortunately it doesn't work. I created a new project where Material3 is already implemented but the colors do not change to the ones I choose.
For example: The color of the button is the same all the time (purple)

[image: Dynamic Color setting]

My button code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button"
            android:id="@+id/button_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textview_first"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

My theme.xml:

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your light theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_light_primary</item> -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Base.Theme.MyApplication" />
</resources>
```